# Getting broken hero swords in Terraria mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is there any way to get broken hero swords easier, or multiply them

Answer (score 0):

Broken Hero Swords only drop during a Solar Eclipse from Frankensteins and Swamp Things. In order to increase the chance of getting one during a Solar Eclipse, use water candles and battle potions so that more enemies will spawn giving you more chances that a broken hero sword drops.

---

### Duplication

*The below is based on a glitch and is not an intended mechanic of the game, an update is likely to fix this behaviour*

An easy way to duplicate items on IOS is to get a safe and a piggy bank (both purchased from the merchant) and place them near each other.

1. Open the safe
2. Drag the object you want to duplicate (broken hero sword) from your inventory into the safe. **Don't push deposit**.
3. Drag a random item into the safe, and again don't push deposit.
4. Go to the piggy bank and you should see your broken hero sword there.
5. Take the items out of the piggy bank.
6. Go back to the safe and you should see a second set of the items which you can take.